# google maps API autocomplete - how to handle direct entry

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a google autocomplete input, and when the user selects one of the suggested addresses I have a *place_changed* function that splits the returned address into the fields necessary for a form, including lat & lng.

If instead the user types in an address and doesn't select one from the autocomplete list, then I need to geocode it to get the information. The *place_changed* function doesn't fire. So, I can put an *onchange* listener on the input which handles the direct user input.

The issue lies in that both the *place_changed* and *onchange* events fire when a suggestion is chosen from the autocomplete list.

Is there a way, in the *onchange* handler, to detect that the reason for it being called is the result of an autocomplete selection? it can then return without taking any further action.

Answer (score 0):

Their is many way to change the address we can put string selection as a fire so when they throw the address Google goes to individual address not by the suggestion like the blue lines can Identifying the photographs not the back view so also needed some more photographer for move futher